# what the meaning for @1 , @2 for .net solution YAML build pipeline

Tags: .net, azure-devops

Could someone please help me understand @1, or @2 here? Is this API version and behind all the API calls?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number after @ represents the task major version.

[image]

This link is useful for you [Yaml File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Semantic versioning have three parts, X.Y.Z, where X, Y and Z are non-negative integers. This means that the primary or major version is X, and the minor version is Y. Bug fixes and patches are called version Z.

Comment: I would suggest adding text from the docs as quote (prefix it with `>`) instead of image.